# Is a release needed on a ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When loading the  ZZZViewController as shown below

```
ZZZViewController *zzzvc = [[ZZZViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ZZZViewController" bundle:nil];
zzzvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:zzzvc animated:YES];
```

do I now do a `[zzzvc release]`;

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you alloc/init'd it. You are responsible for cleaning it up.

Comment: Right. Doesn't matter if it's a view controller or anything else -- if you called -alloc, you'd better call -release at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because :

alloc => +1
presentModalViewController => +1
dismiss => -1

total : +1 not 0. => BAD

release => -1

total : 0 => OK

Comment: Not init, but alloc. Init has nothing to do with retainCount.